# How good is this snippet for running a block in the background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous

I've been using this in my apps to run code in the background but I've been running into some odd performance lag. Sometimes I actually need to specify a time greater than `0.0` but usually it needs to run `NOW`

Is this the best practice or am I setting myself up for failure?

```
dispatch_queue_t dqt = dispatch_queue_create("com.myapp.iphone.fetchRecentContent", NULL);
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dqt, ^{
    ...
});
```

Comment: oltman's answer is correct — you don't need to create your own queue. Out of interest, are you ever destroying your queue?

Comment: @Tommy This current project is written with ARC so I'm not able to run `dispatch_release`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have should work just fine, but a cleaner version is below. As a bonus, I included code necessary to dispatch back to the main thread (fairly common if you're doing some heavy lifting in the background and need to update the UI when it's done).

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
            // background code here
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                // UI thread code here
            });
        });
```

Comment: How can I tell that same script to run after, let's say, 1 second?

Comment: If you want to add a delay, `dispatch_after` is what you want. That line would look something like `dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(num_seconds * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ /* code here */ });`

Comment: Note that you'll want to change the target queue if this is to run in the background.